# stsadm addcontentdb - add content database from sp1 to sp2 environment?

Tags: sql, sharepoint, moss, stsadm

I'm trying to add a content database from a sp1 environment to a sp2 environment, but I am getting the error,

Login failed for user "username". Reason: Not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection

I've tried all accounts, from Farm Admin, Web app account, to SQL Admin

Method's are both true from here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896148

I've not tried mixed auth mode as I don't think I'm allowed to make this change on our SQL servers

Any Ideas??? I do not really want to upgrade contentdb inplace

Comment: Server Fault http://serverfault.com is a better place for this type of question. Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

started working now, added my farm account to admin permissions on SQL box